# SOLR Undefined Field Length

Tags: solr, facet

Using SOLR and the DataImportHandler, we have indexed our database.  The database has a field that contains concatenated property data for the row.  We use a transformer in our data-config.xml file to read that field and split it into several dynamic fields.

We use this data to search against as facets.

We can search *some* of the fields as facets and it works perfectly, however, some of the fields cannot do a facet search (e.g. fq=attr_fieldname:"facetval").  When searching, they return "HTTP Status 400 - undefined field Type" or "HTTP Status 400 - undefined field Length"

We can see the dynamic fields are created when viewing the schema browser, so there isn't a question on whether or not the field name is correct.

In our schema.xml, the dynamic field is defined as a string type that does not allow multivalued.

Any ideas about what is causing this, or what we can do to prevent it?

Thanks!

UPDATE---
Here is the dynamic field definition that we're using:

```
  <dynamicField name="attr_*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false"/>
```

UPDATE 2---
Is anyone aware of an issue caused by a dynamic field that would end up being named "attr_type" or "attr_length"?
Based on one of the comments, it was suggested that maybe we were sending "length" or "type" as a field name.  We aren't doing that, but we are sending "attr_length" or "attr_type"

Comment: can you post your dynamicField declarations?

Comment: updated the post to include the definition...

Comment: that looks ok... are you maybe referring to a field named `Type` or `Length` you don't have defined?